# Copied DateTime values aren't equal

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have something like the following:

```
var obj1 = new MyClass
{
    StartDate = DateTime.Now
};

var obj2 = new MyClass
{
    StartDate = obj1.StartDate
};
```

These objects are then stored by way of Entity Framework, and later I try to fetch entities by comparing their `StartDate` values. What I have found, however, is that this query sometimes returns the expected entities and sometimes not; because these `StartDate` values turn out to differ by a small number of ticks. I don't see how this is possible--it's not as if I assign DateTime.Now to both, instead I explicitly define one in terms of the other.

Comment: Based on what you've shown, I wouldn't expect obj1 and obj2 to be equal to each other, because it's a reference type and they're references to different object. Did you [take any steps to compare them by value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type)?

Comment: You should add a full example showing the comparison going wrong. Are you actually storing them to the database and retrieving them before comparing?

Comment: When writing to console, try `StartDate.ToString("o")` or `@" … {StartDate:o} … "` etc. to see the full precision and an indication of the `Kind`. Precision will most likely be lost if you store to a database (depending on the DB data type).

Comment: @mason I'm comparing the StartDate values between the objects, not the objects themselves.

Comment: @ManiGandham Yes I am. I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: DateTime is a value type, and will be copied on assignment. As such, if `obj1.Ticks` and `obj2.Ticks` differ subsequently to this assignment, then there must be something interfering in the middle (most likely; loss of precision while loading or storing). You should diagnose this by examining the values at each step (does it store them correctly? Does it load them correctly?). Either way, a simple solution may be to store the `DateTime.Ticks` value directly as a string or long, and reconstruct a DateTime object if or where necessary.